# CPP - Misunderstanding variables behavior

Tags: c++

I am starting coding in CPP, i want to implement Fibonacci algorithm.

Can you explain me why i am getting wrong output?

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a;
    cin >> a;
void fibbo(double a)
{
    double n = 1;
    double m = 0;
    while(n<a){
    n = n+m;
        m=n;
    cout << n << "<" << a << endl;
    }
}
}
```

here is an example and "a" equal 100

[image]

Comment: Hint: are you setting `m` to the old value of `n`, or the new one? Should you be setting it to the old one or the new one?

Comment: Step through it a couple of times in your mind (or with a debugger) and it will become blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is written in such a way, that `m` and `n` are always the same. Write

```
void fibbo(double a)
{
    double n = 1;
    double m = 0;
    while (n<a){
        double t = n + m;
        m = n;
        n = t;
        cout << n << "<" << a << endl;
    }
}
```

instead.